# Почему мы командуем лошади: "Но!"?

Tags: этимология, значение-слов, междометие

Желая поехать или ускориться на лошади, возница командует ей: "**Но!**"
**Что ЭТО**: часть от какого-то старого слова, звуковое подражание чему-то или ещё что-то?

Comment: Поговаривают, что малообразованные командуют "Но!", а лица с высшим образованием - "Ну!".

Answer (score 4):

Обычно лошади командуют : ***"Но***, пошла!"
**Но!** является вариантом **Ну!**, и выражение существует ***"окололошадиное"*** — *не **ну**кай, не запряг еще!*
Команда **Но!** гораздо громче, легче и отчётливее произносится — в отличие от **Ну!**, которая говорится неизбежно "в нос".

Comment: Да. Но почему же мы обращаемся к лошади на "ты"? Ведь никто ещё ни с одной лошадью, кажется не пил на брудершафт.

Comment: Вообще, все командуют по-разному. Сколько я работала с лошадьми, никогда на них "но" не кричала. Когда лошадь под седлом, ей вообще голосовые команды не нужны, а запряженной в телегу... я катала детей в парке, и просто говорила коню "пошли".)))

Comment: >Н.А.Некрасов, Школьник  (1856)  
- **Ну, пошел же**, ради бога!  
Небо, ельник и песок -  
Невеселая дорога..  
- Эй, садись ко мне, дружок!

В первой строчке к кому обращаются - к коню или юноше?  
)))

Comment: Возможно,  связано  с  "нудить",  "принудить",  "принуждать".

Comment: Это все замечательно! Но именно в этом-то и вопрос. При общении с людьми мы, мотивируя их в резкой форме, допустимо говорим/спрашиваем : "Ну?! Ну, давай! Ну ты, блин!"... Но никогда не "Но!", так как это воспринимается уже как союз противопоставления (поправьте меня). И обратная сторона: если уж такое "понукание" появилось, то почему в отношении лошадей закрепилось "но", а не привычное "ну"?

Answer (score 2):

Слово **понукать** — от возгласа "**Ну**!". Его часто заменяют "**Но!**" — кому как нравится, вернее, как получается. А вот почему именно этот возглас, сказать трудно.
Междометия вообще трудно объяснить, в разных языках они разные, даже звукоподражания: в одних — **ку-ка-ре-ку!**, в других — **ко-ко-ри-ко**!, в третьих — ещё страннее, а ***наше*** им тоже кажется странным.

По отношению к лошадям звук ничего не обозначал. Просто нужно было приучить лошадь к какой-то команде голосом — покороче. У лошади хорошая память, она запоминает, какой звук издавал хозяин, посылая её вперёд, а посылал он её прикосновением: разговор с лошадью — разговор прикосновений. Вперёд посылали кнутом или шпорой и одновременно кричали или спокойно говорили: "**Но!"**.  Быкам — "Цоб-цобэ" или ещё что-то. Потом животное привыкало к голосу, кнут уже был не нужен. Кто-то просто говорил: "Пошла... Пошёл..."

А "**тпру-у-у**" — это уже звукоподражание. Натягивали поводья, у лошади вырывалось фырканье, похожее на "**тпр**", хозяин его повторял, лошадь тоже запоминала, потом уже и поводья были не нужны.

Answer (score 0):

Действительно: к  людям — **"ну"**,  к  лошадям — **"но".**
А  ***само  слово*** — и  междометие,  и  союз,  и  частица ( **ну**, наконец;  **ну**, пошли;  **ну**, скоро)?
А  по  отношению  к  лошадям, то здесь — только **одно** значение, и громкость нужна. На что уже было указано в первом ответе.
А "**ну**", мне кажется, связано с "**ну**дить" — значение у этой частицы, чаще всего, побудительное. Может, возглас "**ну**" — от слова **понукать** ?

Comment: Хотя,  не  так  прямо,  конечно. Возможно  у  них  предшественники  общие.  Может  это  форма  древнего  повелительного  наклонения ?  Или  производное  от  такой  формы ?  Кажется,  мой  ответ  плавно  перешёл  в  вопрос.

Comment: Уважаемые, можно я еще один "вброс" осуществлю? Уж коль скоро мы обсуждаем этот вопрос в рубрике "этимология", как вы думаете, не связаны ли между собой лошадиное "Но!" и плетка-ногайка?

Comment: Нет.  Во-первых:  потому, что плётка  по  словарям - нагайка.  Во-вторых  название  отражает  происхождение - это  ногайская  плеть,  в  России  слово  известно  с  18-го  века.  В  первом  слоге  "а",  но  это  уже
фонетика.

Answer (score 0):

Фасмер не дает прямой єтимологи для но, но вот "тпру" объясняет не звукоподражанием (вряд ли бы этот звук был общим у коров и лошадей).

тпру!

межд., тпру́га "подзывание коров"., тпру́сень – то же по отношению к теленку, вятск. (Васн.), тпрселя "ласкат. обращение к лошади", тпрсё, тпрсель "подзывание лошади", витебск. (Этногр. Обзор. 34, 62). Основано на ономатопоэтическом образовании.

По поводу "Но" могу предположить, что развилось оно из "чмокающего" звука, напоминающего стук подковы (цок или чок), которым ямщики часто сопровождали свои действия.